# Upload .eml files to Gmail over IMAP

Tags: bash, email, python, gmail, imap

I have a bunch of directories of eml files that I want upload to gmail using IMAP. I've used IMAPSync in the past to sync two IMAP accounts but these messages are just sitting on a file system as eml files they are not in an existing IMAP account where I can sync them. The eml files are all named via message ID. I want to maintain all the message properties and message attachments so that when they are in gmail I can search them and view them as complete messages. The file structure is as such.

```
2015mailarchives
├── 010115.xyz.archive
│   ├── account.manager
│   │   └── in
│   │       ├── 65199001.eml
│   │       ├── 65754836.eml
│   │       ├── 65860605.eml
│   │       ├── 65867970.eml
│   │       ├── 65990249.eml
│   │       ├── 65998348.eml
│   │       ├── 66004688.eml
│   │       ├── 66022610.eml
│   │       ├── 66107473.eml
│   │       ├── 66254739.eml
│   │       ├── 66293987.eml
│   │       ├── 66304813.eml
│   │       └── 66317500.eml
│   ├── adam.beck
│   │   ├── in
│   │   │   ├── 64633604.msg.eml
│   │   │   ├── 64634191.msg.eml
│   │   │   ├── 64635386.msg.eml
│   │   │   ├── 64635388.msg.eml
```

I don't really have to maintain the file structure. All I am trying to accomplish is to create a backup of the messages that can be searched quickly on gmail.

Any ideas on how to accomplish such a task? The files are on a headless linux box so I was hoping for something in bash, perl, python, etc.

Comment: Are those regular plain-text .eml's or MS Outlook binary .eml's?

Comment: Plain text. I can read them in vi.

Answer (score 1):

Many "mailbox sync" tools also support the Maildir and/or MH storage formats alongside IMAP. Conveniently, both of them consist of simple directories with one file per message:

- To turn a directory into a Maildir folder (supported by nearly all programs), first create subdirectories `cur`, `new`, `tmp`, then move all message files under `new/`.
- Alternatively, in case the program needs MH format, rename all messages by number (`1`, `2`, `3`… – no extension or anything) and create a blank `.mh_sequences` file.

Now that the directory is a valid Maildir folder, you can use OfflineIMAP or imapsync to transfer its contents somewhere else. Or run `mutt -f account.manager/` to open the directory as a mail folder in Mutt; use <kbd>Shift+T</kbd> `.` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select all messages, and <kbd>Shift+C</kbd> `imaps://foo@imap.gmail.com` <kbd>Enter</kbd> to copy them to the IMAP server.

**Note:** This assumes standard RFC 822 formatted messages in those .eml files – it won't work with Outlook's binary .eml format.

Also, beware of [Google Apps' bandwidth limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1071518?hl=en) – you can upload up to 500 MB per month.